# Correctly migrating from JDK-8 to JDK-11 for JAX-WS libraries

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jax-ws, java-11

I am developing a couple of integrations (as Maven projects) between several defect management systems, one of which exposes services through WSDL, forcing me to consume them through WS.
For the latter I succesfully developed the code for JDK-8 and everything works.

I am now in the middle of JDK migration from 8 to 11 and need to update the integration that makes use of WS. I understood that in Java 11 some EE libraries (including JAX-WS) were removed.
I then surfed the Web in order to get rid of this problem, but after a couple of days of tests and cut-and-paste of depenendencies I still have the same problem: cannot instantiate the WS to interact to the final server (that is a CA SDM 14.1).

Currently I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getInstance()
```

And my POM file looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <target.dir>target</target.dir>
    <app.version>4.0.0</app.version>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.resources.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClassName>unipol.alm.integrations.FireStarter</mainClassName>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
    <json.version>20210307</json.version>
    <apache.http.components.version>4.5.9</apache.http.components.version>
    <derby.version>10.14.2.0</derby.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
    <octane.cucumber.version>12.60.48</octane.cucumber.version>
    <commons.version>2.5</commons.version>
    <json.simple.version>1.1.1</json.simple.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${json.simple.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.http.components.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.http.components.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>${derby.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>${derby.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hpe.alm.octane</groupId>
        <artifactId>octane-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${octane.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
        <artifactId>smbj</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-vfs</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-vfs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
        <version>20050927</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

where from `javax.xml.ws` are all the dependencies added to make JAX-WS working on JDK 11 (added following the consecutive exceptions the code was giving through NoClassDefFoundError).

Moreover, I generated the Java classes from the WSDL exposed by the defect management system with the following in my POM (just the first time):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>
                    wsimport
                </goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>http://defect.management.system/ServiceDefinition?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <packageName>com.ca.unicenterserviceplus.servicedesk</packageName>
        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</sourceDestDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then copied and pasted the generated files in the `com.ca.unicenterserviceplus.servicedesk` where they are expected to be found by the application.

My question after all this: is there a way to make things work as they were with JDK 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Oracle release notes for Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html), I found this:

> other-libs ➜ JEP 320 Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules
>
> Remove the Java EE and CORBA modules from the Java SE Platform and the
> JDK. These modules were deprecated in Java SE 9 with the declared
> intent to remove them in a future release (JEP 320).
>
> The following modules have been removed from Java SE 11 and JDK 11:
>
> ```
> java.xml.ws (JAX-WS, plus the related technologies SAAJ and Web Services Metadata)
> java.xml.bind (JAXB)
> ```

...etc

According to what I read from Oracle, they removed Jax-WS from Java 11, but it's still available under OpenJDK: [JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).  According to that page,

> This proposal assumes that developers who wish to compile or run
> applications on the latest JDK can find and deploy alternate versions
> of the Java EE technologies. **The Reference Implementations (RIs) of
> JAX-WS and JAXB are a good starting point because they are complete
> replacements for the java.xml.ws and java.xml.bind modules in JDK 9.**
> The RIs are available as Maven artifacts: (note that they must be
> deployed on the class path)
>
> ```
> com.sun.xml.ws : jaxws-ri (JAX-WS, plus SAAJ and Web Services Metadata)
> com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-ri (JAXB)
> ```
>
> The tools for JAX-WS and JAXB are also available as Maven artifacts:
>
> ```
> wsgen and wsimport: com.sun.xml.ws : jaxws-tools, plus tool scripts
> schemagen and xjc: com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-jxc and com.sun.xml.bind : jaxb-xjc, plus tool scripts
> ```

Since you are on Java 8, you may still have to do more tweaking and/or migrate up to Java 9 first, but from I can tell, this is your only path forward.

So to summarize, Oracle removed Jax-WS and related technologies from Java 11, but they are still available to download and use and here is the link to the Maven repo for [(RIs) of JAX-WS and JAXB](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sun.xml.ws%20AND%20a:jaxws-ri) .
James

Comment: Thank you James! Sorry for being late with the response: we managed to have a talk with the team that manages the SOA endpoint, and in the near future they will assist us to migrate on the REST interface this tool exposes. Your answer is clear and complete, so I am marking it as the correct answer on this topic!

Comment: Migrations can be difficult and challenging, I'm happy I was able to offer some assistance.